# Keyboard doesn't work on GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, keyboard

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on an Acer Aspire VN7-792G laptop.

The keyboard was working normally until one day it suddenly stopped working on Grub menu. I can't select OS or even enter BIOS. But it normally boots into Ubuntu after waiting out the normal GRUB timeout (10 seconds I think), and the keyboard works fine then.

I tried to do some research and come across 'ohci_pci' and 'initramfs' but I couldn't understand how to apply them to my case or if they are even relevant to my case.

I would appreciate it if anyone can help.

Comment: The OS has no control over whether you go into BIOS or select from GRUB.  Sounds like the motherboard might need a reset procedure performed on it.  If your laptop has a removable battery, remove it and all other power from it.  Press the power button a bunch of times then hook the power back up.  If the battery is not removable.  Disconnect all other power and cables from the system then press and hold the power button for 15+ seconds.  Then hook the power back up and try again.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work. For what it's worth, when I press F2 or F12 during the boot splash it does enter to BIOS, but can't proceed from that because I previously setup a password for it, and the keyboard doesn't work so I can't type it :-(.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2379525&p=13718691#post13718691

"You could insert the GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="at_keyboard" to verify keyboard. Usually c or e during grub, then add the line to the end of your kernel grub line.

You could also add the line to your /etc/default/grub file so it's added automatically after kernel upgrade or compiling."

I couldn't use the first option, but the second worked. It still doesn't work when I try to enter BIOS and I can't type the password. I'll update as soon as I find a solution for this as well.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I switched the keyboard to a new USB port and it worked.

Even if the keyboard worked fine after boot.

Worth a try.

Comment: It is an internal laptop keyboard, so that does not work.